# useRef and useEffect not triggering on dependency change problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have a useEffect question/bug in my code. I would like to have a custom input field to upload an image. So I use useRef and pass it to the ProfileImageOption component. After the upload component the image's get url (avatarUrlPut) is updated and useEffect should call the getPhoto() function and re-render the component. But it is not happenning.

I have found this blogpost related to my issue. But blogpost is not providing a solution idea around the bug. https://coder.earth/post/react-hooks-oops-part-3-an-effect-does-not-run-again-when-its-dependencies-change

I have read from the official documentation that when useRef is used, useEffect will not be able to re-render the component because useRef doesn't notify React when it's current property changes. I suspect a similar issue here but I didn't understand it completely. Would someone help? Thank you.

```js
function EmployeeHeader(props) {
  const {avatarUrlPut, avatarUrlPost} = props 
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const userID = useSelector((state) => state.auth.fetchUserSuccess.id)

  useEffect(() => {
  // After uploading the image avatarUrlPut is changed and it is on the dependency array of useEffect
    dispatch(getPhoto(avatarUrlPut)) 
      console.log("Am I called after an upload?") // No!
  }, [dispatch, avatarUrlPut])

  const [uploadedImage, setUploadedImage] = useState({})

  const uploadImage = useRef()
  const openCameraModal = useRef()
  return (
    <div>
      <ColorizedRect width={'100%'} height={'175px'}>
        <Image
          source={avatarUrlPut}
          className={'profile_image'}
          spinnerwidth={'140px'}
          spinnerheight={'175px'}
        />
        <ProfileImageOption
          onClick={() => uploadImage.current.click()}
          icon={'upload'}
          top={'80px'}
        ></ProfileImageOption>
        <input
          id="uploadAvatar"
          ref={uploadImage}
          type="file"
          accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,"
          style={{display: 'none'}}
          onChange={(e) =>
            dispatch(uploadPhoto(e.target, avatarUrlPost, setUploadedImage, handleShow))
          }
        />
        <a href={avatarUrlPut} download="Avatar.jpg">
          <ProfileImageOption icon={'download'} top={'125px'}></ProfileImageOption>
        </a>
      </ColorizedRect>
    </div>
  )
}
export default EmployeeHeader
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure `avatarUrlPut` is actually changing? It's hard to judge with the code you provided because it's clearly not happening in this component.

Comment: yes it is from parent component and fetched from redux store via useSelector. I am so sure that it is changing, even if I download the image after the upload new image is downloaded...